# adding a point in a manipulate command

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate, mathematical-optimization

I am having trouble adding a point to mark the Min values of each parabola when using the Manipulate command?

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[x^2 - 2*(a - 2)*x + a - 2, {a, -20, 20}, 
  PlotRange -> {-200, 200}], {a, -10, 10}]
```

This gives me the parabolas but how do I get a vertex point visible as it moves with parameter a.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the options [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html), [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) and [`MeshStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshStyle.html) as follows:

```
Manipulate[Plot[x^2 - 2*(a - 2)*x + a - 2, {x, -20, 20}, 
  ClippingStyle -> False,
  MeshFunctions -> {# &}, 
  Mesh -> {{a - 2}}, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red], 
  PlotRange -> {-200, 200}], {a, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html)

```
Manipulate[Plot[x^2 - 2*(a - 2)*x + a - 2, {x, -20, 20}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{a - 2, -6 + 5 a - a^2}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {-200, 200}], {a, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

where I have used the results from:

```
Minimize[x^2 - 2*(a - 2)*x + a - 2, x]
```

> ```
>  {-6 + 5 a - a^2, {x -> -2 + a}}
> ```