# getting the coordinates

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

With the given function from a previous problem I was solving [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/231664/adding-a-point-in-a-manipulate-command), I want to create/collect the coordinate points of Min. value for 21 values of parameter **a** (from -7 to 7), and find a,b, and c such that the points are on the curve of the quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=y$. I also want to use the plot command to show this coordinate system with the parabola obtained from it.

$ax^2 + b+x +c=y$ goes through all the minimum points for the curves you created

Comment: The function in the linked question does not have a parameter `p`. Please edit your post and add the correct function.

Comment: the parameter was changed

Comment: `f[a_, x_] = x^2 - 2*(a - 2)*x + a - 2; Assuming[-7 <= a <= 7,
 Minimize[{f[a, x], -20 <= x <= 20, -7 <= a <= 7}, x] // Simplify]` gives `{-6 + 5 a - a^2, {x -> -2 + a}}`

Comment: yes this was from the link I referenced. It gives the equation of the vertex (x,y), where x is a-2 and y is -6 + 5 a - a^2. As you move the parameter a, the vertex coordinates changes.

Comment: You are difficult to understand since `a x^2 + b x + c == 0 ` is not a curve as you called it. Is this what you want: `tab = Table[{a, a - 2}, {a, -7, 7, 14/20}] ` and `Solve[{#[[1]] == a, #[[1]]*#[[2]]^2 + b #[[2]] + c == 0}, {a, c, 
      b}][[1]] & /@ tab // Quiet ` ?

Comment: @Akku14 I changed the function because there was a typo it's suppose to be ax^2+b+x+c=y. It goes through all the minimum points for the curves created. it's supposed to look like this https://imgur.com/NbqIohn