# plotting parabolas

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I had to redo the problem because there was a mistake. With the given function from a previous problem, I was solving [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/231664/adding-a-point-in-a-manipulate-command), I found that the parabola created a trajectory on the graph, ie another parabola.

I'm trying to create a plot where I collect the coordinate points of Min. value for 21 values of parameter **a** (from -7 to 7), and find a,b, and c such that the points are on the curve of the quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=y$. The plot looks something like this

[image]

The curve of $ax^2 + b+x +c=y$ goes through all the minimum points for the curves created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood the question correctly. Does this solve your question?

```
Table[{Plot[x^2-2*(a-2)*x+a-2,{x,-20,20}],{a-2,-6+5 a-a^2}},{a,Range[-7,7,14/20]}];
Show[Flatten[{%[[All,1]],Plot[x-x^2,{x,-20,20},PlotStyle->Red],ListPlot[%[[All,2]]]}]]
-6+5 a-a^2/.a->x+2//Expand
```

[image: Parabolas]

I used the code from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/231665/42436 to generate the parabolas and from the formula for the minima `{a-2,-6+5 a-a^2}` one can directly compute the parabola on which all minima are found:
$$x-x^2=y\\ a x^2+b x+c=y\quad\text{with}\quad \{a=-1,b=1,c=0\}$$

Comment: How can I find the coordinates using Solve command?

Comment: What coordinates?

Comment: nevermind, it was found using table command.

Answer (score 2):

To get the  trajectory equation about the minimum, we can do as below.

```
f[x_, a_] := x^2 - 2*(a - 2)*x + a - 2;
min = Minimize[f[x, a], x];
Eliminate[{x, y} == ({x, y} /. Last@min /. y -> First@min), a]
```

> -y == -x + x^2

To plot the minimum points, here we also use `Mesh`.

```
Clear["`*"];
f[x_, a_] := x^2 - 2*(a - 2)*x + a - 2;
curves = Plot[Table[f[x, a], {a, -7, 7, 14/20}], {x, -20, 20}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[Small], Cyan}];
min = Minimize[f[x, a], x];
trajectory = 
  ParametricPlot[{x, y} /. Last@min /. y -> First@min, {a, -9, 9}, 
   MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, a}, a], 
   Mesh -> {Range[-7, 7, 14/20]}, 
   MeshStyle -> {PointSize[Medium], Red}, PlotStyle -> Yellow];
Show[curves, trajectory]
```

Another way is `Show` the minimum points by `Graphics`

```
points = Graphics[{Red, 
    Table[Point[{x, y} /. Last@min /. y -> First@min], {a, -7, 7, 
      14/20}]}];
```

[image]