# Marking the minimum point of a quadratic

Tags: plotting, manipulate

```
Clear[a]
Manipulate[
  Plot[ a*x^2 + 2*x + a, {x, -40, 40}, PlotRange -> {-15, 15}], 
  {a, -10, 10}]
```

I want to mark the minimum value in this range with a blue coloured dot, how can I do this? I tried using `MeshStyle`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Minimum value or extrema (max or min)? Depending on $a$ your function can have either.

Comment: Minimum or maximum depending on which one goes the farthest

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adding a point in a manipulate command](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/231664/adding-a-point-in-a-manipulate-command)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply plot the extremum point with `Epilog` inside `Plot` as you know it exactly. For more complicated functions you might need to use `FindMinimum` etc. to give you the value.

```
Manipulate[
Plot[a x^2+2x+a,{x,-40,40}, 
Epilog->{Blue,PointSize[.015],Point[{-1/a,(-1 + a^2)/a}]},
PlotRange -> {-15, 15}], 
{{a,.1}, -10, 10,.003}]
```

Comment: i wanted to ask, why do we add -1/a,(-1 + a^2)/a? what does it give and how? thanks

Comment: @Aran as I said in the post it is the coordinate of extremum (max or min).